# React Context State Variables in useEffect dependency array causing local app to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-context

just trying to figure out what I may be doing wrong here. For some reason, the app just keeps getting into a loop and crashing when I pass in the variables in the dependency array. These are state variables from the context provider.

I am trying to get this useEffect hook to run everytime the variables in the dependency array is ran:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Setting default values
    const minSqFt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minSqFt'));
    const maxSqFt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('maxSqFt'));
    toggleBySqft(minSqFt, 'min');
    toggleBySqft(maxSqFt, 'max');

    const minPrice = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minPrice'));
    const maxPrice = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('maxPrice'));
    toggleByPrice(minPrice, 'min');
    toggleByPrice(maxPrice, 'max');
  }, [filterBySqFt, filterByPrice]);
```

The filterBySqFt and filterByPrice are state variables from the context provider. It is being pulled in from props.

Here are some functions that are related to the above code but shouldn't have to do with the app crashing.

```
  const handleSelectSqFt = (e, param) => {
    if (param === 'min') localStorage.setItem('minSqFt', e.value);
    if (param === 'max') localStorage.setItem('maxSqFt', e.value);
  }

  const handleSelectPrice = (e, param) => {
    if (param === 'min') localStorage.setItem('minPrice', e.value);
    if (param === 'max') localStorage.setItem('maxPrice', e.value);
  }
```

And here is where I am using the functions. toggleByPrice and toggleBySqFt are the actual functions from the app context provider that updates the state in app context file:

```
<div>
            <h3 className={cl("filters_title")}>Price</h3>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Min Price</div>
              <Select
                options={price_min_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleByPrice(e.value, "min");
                  handleSelectPrice(e, "min");
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={
                  filterByPrice.min !== -1 ? filterByPrice.min : "Any"
                }
                isSearchable={false}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Max Price</div>
              <Select
                options={price_max_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleByPrice(e.value, "max");
                  handleSelectPrice(e, "max")
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={
                  filterByPrice.max !== -1 ? filterByPrice.max : "Any"
                }
                isSearchable={false}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3 className={cl("filters_title")}>Square Footage</h3>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Min sq. ft.</div>
              <Select
                options={sqft_min_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleBySqft(e.value, "min");
                  handleSelectSqFt(e, 'min');
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={filterBySqft.min !== -1 ? filterBySqft.min : "Any"}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Max sq. ft.</div>
              <Select
                options={sqft_max_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleBySqft(e.value, "max");
                  handleSelectSqFt(e, 'max');
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={filterBySqft.max !== -1 ? filterBySqft.max : "Any"}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Updated:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    
    // toggleBySqFt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minSqFt'), 'min'));
// toggleBySqFt(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('maxSqFt'), 'max'));
    // toggleByPrice(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minPrice'), 'min'));
    // toggleByPrice(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('maxPrice'), 'max'));

  }, []);


  const handleSelectSqFt = (e, param) => {
    if (param === 'min') {
      localStorage.setItem('minSqFt', e.value);
      toggleBySqft(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minSqFt')), 'min');
    } 
    if (param === 'max') {
      localStorage.setItem('maxSqFt', e.value);
      toggleBySqft(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minSqFt')), 'max');
    } 
  }
```

Comment: What are your toggleByPrice and toggleBySqFt functions doing? If they're updating the price and sqft state values, that could cause an infinite loop, because when they update, the useEffect will run, which will cause them to update, which will cause the useEffect to run, etc.

Comment: @esinator Yep, that is what they are doing. Is there any way to combat this?

Comment: What is the purpose of having filterBySqFt, filterByPrice in dependency list of useEffect in first place?

Comment: If the goal is to allow the user to select a toggle option and change what's being displayed as a result, you may not need the useEffect and may be able to put the logic for what you're trying to accomplish in the change handlers. A useEffect is helpful when you need to listen for changes to a particular state value and run code in response, but since the change  is user-driven, I'd consider putting the toggle logic and the getting of the min/max values from local storage in the change handler.

Comment: @esinator Thank you for your input! So the goal is also to load the values on to the user interface as soon as the user lands on the page. The values should be coming from the localStorage. I have took your suggestion and moved it all out of the useEffect and into the handlers. However, the values are not being updated to localstorage on mount. I will update the post to show what I changed

Comment: @Andyally Its to have the values update. Because at first with an empty dependency array, the toggles will not show any ui changes

Comment: @JimJones ah in that case, comment those toggle functions back in and leave the dependency array of the useEffect empty so that those values are grabbed from local storage only on component mount. After that, user interaction will drive subsequent state updates and re-renders.